# Android get data from Application without API

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android app where I need to integrate data from another app.

Just For Example: Think a situation I have ***Google play store*** in my mobile. Now when a person searches "education" in ***play store*** It shows all the result in list which consists that keyword. Now I want to get all the data result fetched by ***play store***  in my app.

Note:- I am not sure there is any code to get data from another app, but still I saw an app called [App for all taxi cabs](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cabsguru) It shows all the result from various application even there is no API for ***ola cabs***, ***Taxi for sure*** and many others but they are somehow manage to get all these data for their app.

Please help I crucially want to know if there is possibility to do so or not.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is "snoop" on another app. That is, you want to retrieve data from it that it doesn't publicly expose in it's API.

I believe this is generally impossible without breaking the encapsulation of the app - this means you would have to use more than its publicly documented (and reliable) interface, and delve into its implementation specifics which are liable to change without warning, thus breaking your own app.

There are apps that are able to take screenshots of other apps, this would be one example of how you could indirectly break the encapsulation, as you could attempt to parse the data that way. I give this example purely to prove that it is possible, however this would be considered terrible practice and should be avoided for many reasons.

For all serious use cases, I would say that if it is not provided in the API, you cannot obtain the data.